# Nested For Loop Result

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I Have a query about a nested for loop result.

**Code**

```
dieCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Die1 = random.randint(1,10)
dieCount[Die1] = dieCount[Die1] + 1

Die2 = random.randint(1,10)
dieCount[Die2] = dieCount[Die2] + 1

Die3 = random.randint(1,10)
dieCount[Die3] = dieCount[Die3] + 1


print ("Dice Roll Stats:")
index = 1
print ("\nFace Frequency")
while index < (len(dieCount)):
    print (index)
    for number in range(dieCount[index]):
        print ("*")
    index = index + 1
```

**Result:**

```
Face Frequency
1
2
3
4
*
5
6
*
7
8
9
*
10
```

For the life of me i cant figure out how to get a result like such:

```
Face Frequency
1
2
3
4*
5
6*
7
8
9*
10
```

If not an answer please guide me to the rite material so I may read through it, I have attempted many different alteration of the code but I still haven't com-up with a decent result. I can use print ("*",end='') but that will append the * before the number. Like wise  I tried something like print (index,"*") and then del dieCount[Die1] etc.. to remove the duplicate numbers however that will remove the number completely out of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
index = 1
print ("\nFace Frequency")
while index < (len(dieCount)):
    output = str(index)
    for number in range(dieCount[index]):
        output += "*"
    print(output)
    index = index + 1
```

However I would write it like this:

```
import random

dieCount = [0]*10

for i in range(3):
    dieCount[random.randint(0,9)] += 1

for i,v in enumerate(dieCount):
    print(str(i) + v * '*')
```

Note that your code has one bug, your list is initialized with 11 zeros, but your random only produces 10 possible numbers. The list index in Python starts from 0, so you were missing the first item of the list all along.

Comment: Great thank you, I Tried something like this, I must have written it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested loop. You can use string multiplication and just append it to the end of your initial print statement like so:

```
while index < (len(dieCount)):
    print (str(index) + "*" * dieCount[index])
    index += 1
```